# Choosing between safe and unsafe HTTP Method when creating MVC action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

I'm generally following the recommendations when it comes to choosing between HTTP GET and HTTP POST as allowed method for action on controller in ASP.NET MVC.

When there is no change on server side, aka I want to retrieve a resource, HTTP GET is allowed.

When user is about to submit some data that will be persisted, HTTP POST is required.

Now here comes the issue with the gray zone:

> What if user wants to download a file?

Usually I would set this as HTTP GET (file is stored in database due to security reasons) as there is no change done on the server.

> What if I want to log that file X was downloaded by user Y?

There is now server-side change as new log is created. Is that a good enough reason to change HTTP method from GET to POST?

Comment: Is the user logged in to the site already before downloading?

Comment: Yes, but it does not make much of a difference really.

Comment: downloading a file should be a GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found exact explanation on how to deal with this:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Definition of safe methods:

> 9.1.1 Safe Methods
>
> Implementors should be aware that the software represents the user in
>   their interactions over the Internet, and should be careful to allow
>   the user to be aware of any actions they might take which may have an
>   unexpected significance to themselves or others.
>
> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and
>   HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
>   other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe".
>   This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT
>   and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the
>   fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.
>
> Naturally, it is not possible to ensure that the server does not
>   generate side-effects as a result of performing a GET request; in
>   fact, some dynamic resources consider that a feature. The important
>   distinction here is that the user did not request the side-effects, so
>   therefore cannot be held accountable for them.

Important part is emphasized below, which gives resolution to my problem:

> Naturally, it is not possible to ensure that the server does not
>   generate side-effects as a result of performing a GET request; in
>   fact, some dynamic resources consider that a feature. The important
>   distinction here is that the user did not request the side-effects, so
>   therefore cannot be held accountable for them.

So since user did not request the logging to be performed, it is considered to be side-effect and therefore I can continue setting GET as HTTP method for file download.